# Validating dates in symfony2

Tags: symfony, date

I'm using the date field in my forms. But when I'm validating with invalids dates, the date field error messages are not displayed. This happens if I have configured the field with 'widget' => 'choice', if I set it up with 'widget' => 'single_text' everything works fine. it's a bug?

Answer (score 1):

When using single text it's also necessary to specify the format required e.g.

```
$builder->add('startDate','date', array('input' => 'datetime', 'widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
```

hope that helps.